# How to count the number of objects in .json

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, dictionary

How do you count the number of different objects in this array json file. A single object is :

```
{
    "short_name": "Demo",
    "roi_number": 0,
    "finding": "null",
    "dt": 0.1,
    "norm_times_series": [
      [80.0, 68.16335617854995, 91.83664382145005],
      [80.0, 67.66379980989896, 92.33620019010104],
      [83.0, 72.78200156354234, 93.21799843645766],
      [83.0, 71.22165069319166, 94.77834930680834],
      [81.0, 67.74249757065954, 94.25750242934046],
      [80.0, 67.12186571458821, 92.87813428541179],
      [81.0, 68.71545011387893, 93.28454988612107]]
   }
```

In the example below there is 4.

```
[
  {
    "short_name": "Demo",
    "roi_number": 0,
    "finding": "null",
    "dt": 0.1,
    "norm_times_series": [
      [80.0, 68.16335617854995, 91.83664382145005],
      [80.0, 67.66379980989896, 92.33620019010104],
      [83.0, 72.78200156354234, 93.21799843645766],
      [83.0, 71.22165069319166, 94.77834930680834],
      [81.0, 67.74249757065954, 94.25750242934046],
      [80.0, 67.12186571458821, 92.87813428541179],
      [81.0, 68.71545011387893, 93.28454988612107]]
   },
 {
    "short_name": "Demo",
    "roi_number": 1,
    "finding": "null",
    "dt": 0.1,
    "norm_times_series": [
      [80.0, 68.16335617854995, 91.83664382145005],
      [80.0, 67.66379980989896, 92.33620019010104],
      [83.0, 72.78200156354234, 93.21799843645766],
      [83.0, 71.22165069319166, 94.77834930680834],
      [81.0, 67.74249757065954, 94.25750242934046],
      [80.0, 67.12186571458821, 92.87813428541179],
      [81.0, 68.71545011387893, 93.28454988612107]]
   },
 {
    "short_name": "Demo",
    "roi_number": 2,
    "finding": "null",
    "dt": 0.1,
    "norm_times_series": [
      [80.0, 68.16335617854995, 91.83664382145005],
      [80.0, 67.66379980989896, 92.33620019010104],
      [83.0, 72.78200156354234, 93.21799843645766],
      [83.0, 71.22165069319166, 94.77834930680834],
      [81.0, 67.74249757065954, 94.25750242934046],
      [80.0, 67.12186571458821, 92.87813428541179],
      [81.0, 68.71545011387893, 93.28454988612107]]
   },
 {
    "short_name": "Demo",
    "roi_number": 3,
    "finding": "null",
    "dt": 0.1,
    "norm_times_series": [
      [80.0, 68.16335617854995, 91.83664382145005],
      [80.0, 67.66379980989896, 92.33620019010104],
      [83.0, 72.78200156354234, 93.21799843645766],
      [83.0, 71.22165069319166, 94.77834930680834],
      [81.0, 67.74249757065954, 94.25750242934046],
      [80.0, 67.12186571458821, 92.87813428541179],
      [81.0, 68.71545011387893, 93.28454988612107]]
   }
]
```

Im working in react and I'm passing this json file through as a prop so I would need to manipulate the prop. I want to know how many different entries are in the json file so I can display the number of radio buttons according to this.

```
import React from 'react';

const Test = (props) => {
return (

 console.log(JSON.parse(props).length); // My attempt = prop is ouput.json

)
};
export default Test;
```

my json file is set as in app.js:

```
this.state = { apiResponse: [] };

  .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
```

and i call it by saying

```
<Test test = {this.state.apiResponse}/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your JSON data in `JSON.parse` and then you can access length property on it:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).length
```

Comment: thank you! how can I check if its working console log seems not to be working.

Comment: I added a bit into the question to make it more specific if you could check for me thanks!

Comment: Oh I see, you cannot put console.log in the return statement, move it up outside of the return statement. Plus I've made a little change to original answer, have a look

Comment: Silly question but where does it print as im running it on the local host

Comment: No problem mate, if you're using Chrome then press F12 or `ctrl shift i` to open the developer tools, there in the console you'll be able to see the log if everything's working fine

Comment: oh thanks haha I did that but seems not to be printing anything

Comment: I added a pic of it up in the post

Comment: I'll give you link with working example, give me a minute

Comment: Here you go, please read the comments also:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-goodall-wgw2w?file=/src/App.js

I also just saw one more problem with your code, instead of `JSON.parse(props)` it should be `JSON.parse(props.test)`.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, if **props.data** contains the example JSON you mentioned, then **props.data.length** should already be giving you the number of elements in the array.

If you are passing props as a string, then just do

```
JSON.parse(props);
```

before accessing the object's length.

Comment: does it matter what inital state i put the json file in, as in my code it is                  
       this.state = { apiResponse: [] };

Comment: I added a bit into the question at the end if u could check it for me thanks